# Inequality involving gradient and subgradient

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I stumbled across a proof where I don't get an inequality.
It goes as:
$f$ is log-concave and $\nabla f(x)$ exists almost everywhere.
Then we have
$$\ln f(x) - \ln f(y) \leq \left<g(y), x-y \right>$$
where $g(y)$ denotes the subgradient at $y$ ($x,y$ in the domain of $f$).
Interchanging $x$ and $y$ we get a second inequality. Adding
these two then yields
$$0 \leq \left< g(y) - g(x), x-y \right>.$$
Thus for $y=0$ we have
$$\left<g(x),x \right> \leq \left< g(0),x\right>.$$
So far, so easy. Now, the authors claim that if $x$ is a point where $\nabla f(x)$
exists, then we get
$$\left< \nabla f(x), x \right> \leq \left< g(0), f(x) x \right>,$$
but I don't see how. Could someone help me out?

Comment: It might be helpful if you write out the book and the author so that people can find the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: Since $g$ is the subgradient of $\ln \circ f$, we have
$\nabla (ln \circ f)(x) = 1/f(x) \nabla f(x)$. The gradient is the only subgradient(if it exists at some $x$) and thus the inequality follows right away. Just didn't see the wood for the trees....